# start screen in python

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

im trying to make my own version of battleships based on codeacademy's one just as my first excercise after completing the course.

so far i got this:

```
from Tkinter import *

miPantalla = Tk()

miPantalla.geometry("600x400+0+0")
miPantalla.title("Bienvenido a Battleships")


label1 = Label(miPantalla, text="BATTLESHIPS", fg="blue").grid(row=1, column=8)
label2 = Label(miPantalla, text="Bienvenido a Battleships", fg="black").grid(row=3, column=8)
label3 = Label(miPantalla, text="Pulse cualquier tecla", fg="black").grid(row=4, column=8)

miPantalla.mainloop()
```

This is supposed to be the start screen of the game, so it has its background, the game's title, and the typical "press any key to start". I got stucked in this last part i dont know what should i do after getting key input from the user so the windows restarts.

do you know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code is written, you don't have any place where the key press is accepted or bound to a function. That's why it's not doing anything. Check out this page, http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm, especially the section "Capturing keyboard events"

You'll replace the function `key` defined there with what you want to happen in the game after the key is pressed.